# Functor - what power do they have over other classes that didn't implement operator ( )

Tags: c++, class, function, pointers, functor

I'm trying to understand the "power" of functors.

Okay, so they are pointers to functions, but what can they do that other classes that didn't implement `operator()` can't do?

For instance :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <assert.h>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;


class MultiplyBy
{
    private:
        int factor;

    public:
        MultiplyBy(int x) : factor(x) {}

        int operator () (int other) const
        {
            return factor * other;
        }
};


int main()
{

    MultiplyBy temp(5);
    int myResult = temp(5);  // now myResult holds 25
    cout << myResult << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And we take his other friend

```
class MultiplyOther
{
    private:
        int factor;
    public:
        MultiplyOther(int x) : factor(x) {}
        int invokeMultiplyMe(int _other)
        {
            return _other * factor;
        }
};
```

And do the same thing:

```
int main()
{
    // MultiplyOther

    MultiplyOther notFunctor(4);
    int myOther = notFunctor.invokeMultiplyMe(3);
    cout << myOther << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And we get:

```
25
12
```

Then, what's the real power of the functor? Do both classes save the state, or am I missing something here?

Comment: true power hides in lambdas I think

Comment: @Mr.Anubis: Lambdas are syntactic sugar for functors, they don't have any more power.

Comment: @interjay you can define them at the point of call , capture variables etc . Can you do that with simple functors without passing them as args etc?

Comment: @Mr.Anubis: You can define a local class right before the call. Variable captures in lambdas are syntactic sugar for storing them in class members. Anything that can be done with a lambda can also be done with a functor (though it may be much more verbose). The reverse is not true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For one, they have a unified signature that can be used e.g. by algorithms that only need to know that they have to call something.

In your example, an instance of `MultiplyBy` could be used by any code that expects to call something that takes an `int` and returns one (or types that are constructible from /convertible to `int`). Using your second example would require the code to have knowledge of the `invokeMultiplyByMe` method.

Note that functors are not pointers to functions at all, as stated in the question. They are classes whose instances can be called with the syntax of a function call.

Comment: Aha! `"Using your second example would require the code to have knowledge of the invokeMultiplyByMe method"` Didn't see it coming , +1 !

Comment: @ron BTW, I just saw "... they are pointers to functions..." in your question. This is not true.

Comment: Also of interest: typically functors can be aggressively inlined, making code such as for_each(start, end, functor) typically run faster than for_each(start, end, func_ptr)

Answer (score 1):

Functors do not have any special properties over classes, but they can be used as functions with higher capabilities. A function usually cannot have state, and if it has (by using a static variable) the state is shared among all function calls.\

A functor has all the properties of a class (state, especially), but can be used as a function. A great example is a functor used for STL algorithms:

```
class Add
{
  public:
    Add(){sum = 0;};
    void operator()(int i)
    {
        sum += i;
    }
    int getSum(){return sum;};

    private:
    int sum;
}

int main()
{

std::vector<int> vint;
vint.push_back(2);
vint.push_back(3);
vint.push_back(4);
}

Add adder;

adder = std::for_each( vint.begin(); vint.end(), adder);

cout << adder.getSum();
```

Answer (score 0):

"so they are pointers to functions" - Function pointers and functors are completely different. Former is just a plain pointer to an original function. It does not hold any state. However, functor or function object holds a state. Functor is any class that defines operator(). So, any object of that kind of class can be called in a manner of a function.

Code snippet from C++ primer...

```
template<class T>
class TooBig
{
    private:
    T cutoff;
    public:
    TooBig(const T & t) : cutoff(t) {}
    bool operator()(const T & v) { return v > cutoff; }
};
```

With this class we can create multiple objects with different cutoff values.
TooBig cutoff1(10);
TooBig cutOff2(20);

One of the best places to use a functor is in templates. For ex, take list template. It has a remove_if function which removes any values in the list which returns true from the argument.

list list1; // lets say it has some values
list list2; // lets say it has some values

now, a call to list1.remove_if(cutoff1); // applies all the elments of list1 and removes those which are greater than the value stored in cutOff1.
Similar thing for list2.

thx!